# Output content of a form on the same page for public view

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post

I'm trying to build a simple form with only dropdown option like

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

All I need is when the user selects one of the options, the option to be automatically submitted (without having to click submit) and posted on the same page for public display.
The selection of different users should be viewable as well and just appended to previous users' choices.

For example:
First user selects Volvo, then the page will display

```
Volvo
```

When second user selects Audi, the page will now append his result to the previous user's result

```
Audi, Volvo
```

Thus every visitor will see what the previous user chose.

And so forth. There should be a limit to how many choice are displayed by users, say 100, and beyond that the original choices will be truncated.

Thanks.

Comment: finally where is Your question? what part You cannot organize ?

Comment: to get you going, use this search terms: jQuery Ajax.

Comment: The question is: how do i get this job done. I don't know what to do beyond building the form. Thank you.

Comment: as I understand, Your page is public, like I submitted Audi, You see on page Audi, You submit Volvo, third user see both Audi and Volvo ? am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.. in database create table, and store there users choices.
And on every submit insert the choice into that table. When you show the page select from Your table with limitations ordering by inserted date desc, and filter Your data by that choices before printing or query.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to set the

```
 onchange()
```

event in your select tag to a submission (directing to the same page) and then using passed parameters you can determine that the submission went through.